# Get next td with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, x-editable

I use jquery x-editable and when a field is successfully edited I want to change color of a `<td>` i same `<tr>`. I've tried

```
$(function() {
    $('.editable a').editable({
        url: "/post",
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            $(this).siblings('td.td_class_name').css('color', 'red');
        }
    })
})
```

but it doesn't work. How do I use jquery's selector correctly?

The html structure

```
<table class="editable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">field</a></td>
        <td class="td_class_name">100</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try this  `$(this).next('.td_class_name').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: Please post the corresponding html structure...

Comment: raju: it doesn't work :-( but I have added the html structure in the question

Comment: `$(this).parent().next('td').css(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the display method of x-editable for DOM modification, it's available since version 1.2.0, try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.editable a').editable({
        url: "/post",
        display: function(value, sourceData, response) {
            $(this).next('.td_class_name').css('color', 'red');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this , but not tested

```
$(function() {
$('.editable a').editable({
    url: "/post",
    context: this,
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        $(this).parent().next('td').css('color', 'red');
    }
})
})
```

or

```
$(function() {
$('.editable a').editable({
    var $this=$(this);
    url: "/post",
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        $this.siblings('td.td_class_name').css('color', 'red');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().css("background-color", "red");` colors the `<td>`, but `$(this).parent().parent().css("background-color", "red");` does not color the `<tr>`. Do you know why? I think I should use `$(this).parent().parent().find(".td_class_name").css("background-color", "red");`?